# Forward proxy as a solution. Need guidance

Tags: cookies, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, forward-proxy

I'm currently developing a Flutter desktop application intended to serve as a third-party app for my school's intranet, allowing students to access its services. My objective is to enable my Flutter app to get all the necessary cookies when a user is redirected the intranet website's login page, completes a Cloudflare challenge, and enters their credentials. Specifically, I need to capture all accepted cookies, including the HTTP-only ones, and redirect them to the Flutter app for further subsequent requests.

Chatgpt suggested the use of a forward-proxy. However, given my limited expertise in this area, I am looking for a confirmation to the solution and would be great to any recommendations or guidance of the general implementation description.